# C# need to get fragment from Text

Tags: c#

Hi I need to find longest sequence of words in text that's matching condition: if word is ending with letter N other word should start with letter N. N - could be any letter. For Example:

```
Simple Elephant
Apple Strong
```

So first line is matching my mentioned condition so I need to print it out to console.
Failing to think of an algorithm how this should work.

Comment: Is it a first letter `h` or first word `hi` to match?

Comment: try to improve your question by adding the code you're using.

Comment: i need to get the fragment of the text like if the sentence is : "Hi my name is Sam. my years so good" i need to print out: "is Sam. My years so" and the number in whitch line it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make this code for you. Can answer to your questions.

```
        List<string> sentenses = new List<string>();
        sentenses.Add("hi, my name is Sam.");
        sentenses.Add("Hi,is,settled,drums.");
        sentenses.Add("Add all your sentenses here");

        string longestSentense ="";
        int longestCount = 0;

        foreach(string sentense in sentenses)
        {
            string[] words = Regex.Split(sentense, "[^a-zA-Z]"); // cut sentense by all not letter character
            int count = 0;
            for (int i=0;i<words.Length-1;i++)
            {
                // check if last letter of words[i] is the same letter as the first or words[i+1]
                if(words[i].Equals("") || words[i+1].Equals("")) continue; // don't look to "empty word"
                if (words[i][words[i].Length-1].Equals(words[i + 1][0])) count++;
            }

            // if here is the biggest number of matching words, we save it
            if(count>longestCount)
            {
                longestCount = count;
                longestSentense = sentense;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("The sentence that contains the most of matching words : \n"
            + longestSentense + "\n"
            + " with " + longestCount + " junctions between matching words.");

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: ye that works fine. but i forgot to mention, that i need to pick out the fragment of the text like: if the sentence is:" hi, my name is Sam. My years so good". so i need to print out: "is Sam. My years so" maybe you could help me with this? :)

Comment: ho ... it's a bit complicated and my code has a bug : in the string "hi, my name is Sam. My years so good. Your rate is small", the last sentence will count 2 match but you don't want that, isn't it ?